# how to disable ripple effect from stepper in angular 6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13, is their is an option to remove ripple like tabs and button

Tags: css, sass, angular7

The header of step that can be clicked to select the step that time ripple is coming I want to remove or disable the ripple from this stepper.

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    Content 1
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    Content 2
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Please also explain me how this properties is working . Whether ripples should be disabled for the step headers.

```
@Input()
disableRipple: boolean
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<mat-vertical-stepper [disableRipple]="true">
```

does it. See it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1gz1k?file=app%2Fstepper-vertical-example.html).

Comment: doens't work in Angular 8. And also in the example the ripple still works

Comment: In the linked example, I suggest removing `[disableRipple]="true"` from code, just to see how the stepper looks ***with*** ripple, for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

- It's not **rocket science** to remove ripple effect while on click of
  mat-stepper or changing that step. We can do it by little **CSS hacks** also.
- Angular **adds** some of the CSS **class** while we click on the
  an element so we can changes it in this way.

```
.mat-step-header:hover{
    background-color: white !important;
}
.mat-step-header.cdk-program-focused {
      background-color: white;
  }
.mat-step-header.cdk-mouse-focused{
    background-color: white;
}
.mat-step-header.cdk-focused{
    background-color: white;
}
```